# Exporting state from functional components. Bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, conventions

When building components related to user input, the two ways I've done it is with controlled components or uncontrolled components with refs.
However, one way that it could be done by declaring the variable that will hold the state outside the component and exporting it.

```
export let input;
let setInput;
const Form = props => {
  [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const handleInput = e => setInput(e.currentTarget.value)
  ...
  return <input value={input} onChange={handleInput} />
}
```

Would this be considered bad practice? Are there any issues with this?

Comment: Yes, once your app has multiple `Form` components, what happens to that `input` value that you're exporting? Having it contained in your component and accessing it via refs will insure you're getting the right instance's value

Answer (score 0):

State of a component is a supposed to be an instance property, by declaring state outside of the component you restrict each component instance to have its own state

If you are looking to use state across your App, consider using `ContextAPI` or `Redux`